# how to read json array object using scala -for Gatling test and store them as a map/list

Tags: scala, gatling

Scala gatling test: This is the response that i want to parse, i would like to store order no (eg:AAA) and store the corresponding _links.self.href url link (from $.._embedded.Orders[*] json path ), for each order no and store them either as a map or list

I want to later use retrieve these values in my gatling tests. if order no column value is AAA from the CSV feeder file i read, i will fetch the corresponding URI from the list or map where order no matches AAA in the list or map and use that uri for the post call.

Can you please assist how to parse it using scala, for my gatling test?

```
val orders = 
  Map("AAA" -> "https://service.order.com/80d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a28019509e2904",
 "BBB" -> "https://service.order.com/90d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a2-8019509e2904",
 "CCC" -> "https://service.order.com/100d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a2-8019509e2904")

private val orders: List[(String, Any)] = List(
    (AAA, https://service.order.com/80d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a2-8019509e2904),
    (BBB, https://service.order.com/90d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a2-8019509e2904),
    (CCC, https://service.order.com/100d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a2-8019509e2904))
```

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "Orders": [
      {
        "year": 1990,
        "order": "AAA",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "https://service.order.com/80d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a2-8019509e2904",
            "title": "order",
            "profile": "",
            "name": "order"
          },
          "up": {
            "href": "https://service.order.com/80d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a2-8019509e2904",
            "name": "order"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "year": 1991,
        "order": "BBB",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "https://service.order.com/90d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a2-8019509e2904",
            "title": "order",
            "profile": "",
            "name": "order"
          },
          "up": {
            "href": "https://service.order.com/90d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a2-8019509e2904",
            "name": "order"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "year": 1992,
        "order": "CCC",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "https://service.order.com/100d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a2-8019509e2904",
            "title": "order",
            "profile": "",
            "name": "order"
          },
          "up": {
            "href": "https://service.order.com/100d66cc1-6cb4-4a84-99a2-8019509e2904",
            "name": "order"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

General idea:

- use `ofType[]` on your `jsonPath` check to not save a String, but a Scala Collections AST (`Map` and `List`), see https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/check/#jsonpath
- generate your payload, either with a function (https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/function/#syntax) or with the Pebble template engine (see https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#pebblestringbody)

If you're struggling with Scala, you might want to go with Gatling Java instead.